# How to launch a new cmd window from an existing cmd window?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

Simply typing "cmd" keeps it in the same window. I'd also like to do "cmd /c command" and have it run in a separate window.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use start. For instance:

```
start cmd
```

Comment: you don't even need the "cmd" bit; start on its own will fire off %comspec%

Comment: Is it possible to reload system variables? This new window will use current environment.

Answer (score 19):

Only

> start

will do it also

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8,

1. Type 'cmd' in the app search box(click on windows sign on left bottom followed by a click in the downward arrow)
2. right click on the 'command prompt' app that appears on search and select 'opn new window' option.